# Connectivity between devices plugged into a router ethernet ports

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking, tcpip

If I plug 2 computers into  free ethernet ports in my wifi router will I be able to establish connection between these pc or router does not allow it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this will work.

Most consumer routers don't have the ability to restrict the movement of local traffic between ethernet ports, and those that do have this option disabled by default.